# How do you update to the latest python 3.5.1 version on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, python-3.5, raspberry-pi3

I got my Raspberry Pi yesterday and I am already trying to code with it. I have a program that I was planning to run on it but it is only compatible with Python versions 3.5.0 or 3.5.1 and everything I find on the internet seems to either be outdated, to do with Python 2 or doesn't relate to my problem as I haven't seen anything else that 100% requires Python 3.5 and can cope with 3.4(currently pre-installed). .exe files don't work on Linux. I am new to the Raspberry Pi and with Linux as I have always been a Windows user. Any help is appreciated. Many Thanks - Robert

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
cd ~
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.5.1.tgz
cd Python-3.5.1
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: I followed your steps and I think it worked but now how do I open 3.5? I have tried opening the python 3 idle in the programming bar in the top right but it still opens 3.4.2 o,0. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Did you try `python3 --version` ?

Comment: @robert You may need to restart.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a `deb` package and install that? Directly calling make install is a good way to mess up your system.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering how to accomplish what @Robert was suggesting: There's the [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) package which accomplishes something similar. Just replace `sudo make install` with `sudo checkinstall` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 7):

I would compile it myself (and indeed, have a few times). I'm assuming that you're running Ubuntu or Raspbian. You should be able to [install the dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/a/21551/658):

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential \
                       libncursesw5-dev \
                       libreadline5-dev \
                       libssl-dev \
                       libgdbm-dev \
                       libc6-dev \
                       libsqlite3-dev tk-dev \
                       libbz2-dev
```

Then go [download the source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) and extract it, and then install it:

```
  $ tar -xzvf https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
  $ cd Python-3.5.1
  $ ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

If you're missing a dependency it will probably die at the `./configure` step. But if everything works, you'll have a brand new Python 3.5 install on your Raspberry Pi. Congrats!

Comment: My dependencies were already up to date and when I tried to download the source this happened:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tar -xzvf https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
tar (child): Cannot connect to https: resolve failed
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 128
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tar -xzvf https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
tar (child): Cannot connect to https: resolve failed
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 128
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: For more details, check [my answer here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/56632/17798).